# Show Header when Swipe to Refresh with Jetpack Paging3 Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout, android-paging

**Problem Statement**: Using Paging3 library and need to show loading information in header when user swipes to refresh. I followed the sample provided in the [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/PagingWithNetworkSample).

**Solution**: Tried adding refresh header in `LoadStateAdapter` for with using `pagingAdapter.withLoadStateHeaderAndFooter()`.

```
messagesRecyclerView.adapter = messagesAdapter.withLoadStateHeaderAndFooter(
                header = MessageHeaderStateAdapter(messagesAdapter),
                footer = MessageLoadStateAdapter()
            )
```

But it does not shows the header until I swipe it 5-6 times in quick successions.

[image]

Footer, on other hand, shows just fine with loading more and error layouts based on `LoadState`.

**Error State**

[image]

**Loading More State**

[image]

Any pointers as to how this can be achieved are much appreciated.

Comment: Try adding manually delay in on refresh callback before API Callback

Comment: @MRamzan Its not related to API response. I put some logs and the `onRefresh` method of `OnRefreshListener` is not getting called on swipe.

Comment: case it was the response was quick, so the refresh header or the progress bar was not rendering in that time like its transaction was skipped.

Comment: This can't be case, because I have logs and break points. And they don't get hit.

Answer (score 0):

`withLoadStateHeader` just returns a `ConcatAdapter` that listens to `PREPEND` state. If you want the header to show up during `REFRESH` you can basically copy the code out of that helper, but instead update `LoadStateAdapter` based on `REFRESH` `LoadState` using a listener on your `PagingDataAdapter`

```
val header = MyLoadStateHeader()
adapter.addLoadStateListener { loadStates -> 
    header.loadState = loadStates.refresh 
} 

recyclerView.adapter = ConcatAdapter(header, this)
```